# Android - after click on button execute c++ code(openCV)

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I wrote 300 lines script (openCV) in c++ and I would like to execute the script after clicking on button in application for android. The script takes a image as an input and the output is edited image. I read about NDK but I am not very skilled in C++/Java, so I do not understand it. I am just learning how to do it. Can you advise me how to do it simple as possible?

**Let's say I have simple UI with one button and after click it execute hello world written in c++.**

I know how to code android application but i do not know how to put c++ with android together.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a official tutorial: [Using C++ OpenCV code with Android binary package](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html). It will be easy if you got a IDE like Eclipse to make a JNI project.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than complicating the issue with C++/JNI/NDK you could just rewrite your 300 lines in Java instead.  OpenCV has a Java binding that is basically identical to the C++ calls.  Java syntax is pretty close to C++ so you already have most of your coding work done.  You will have to learn enough Java to handle the basic App framework and button interaction anyway.  Go to the OpenCV site, http://OpenCV.org, and get a copy of the Android SDK and plug it into your development environment (Eclipse or Android Studio).  I am using OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk, but I think 2.4.11 is out.  In your IDE you just import as existing Android project.  It has sample code built in that you can test right away and then modify to add your functionality.

There are some good tutorials available on setting up an IDE to add native code, NDK, JNI, but it is not really necessary to get OpenCV functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your quick respond. It has to be done in NDK. I have installed eclipse and NDK and all is set up but I do not know how to rewrite my script in c++ to JNI. Are there some rules how to rewrite it or wrap it?

Comment: Download the OpenCV SDK for Android and look at the sample code.  The code for tutorial-2-mixedprocessing shows a call from Java to native through JNI.  Use that as a template and add your C++ code.